# How to update a field with a count of rows from another table on PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

So for a full 2 years I used to simply just write open pg version 9 something like

```
update tableA a
set columnA = (select sum(column_that_I_need_to_count) from tableB b where st_contains(a.geom, b.geom))
```

But for some reason updating like this does not work on my new database version 10. It just runs the update indefinitely and never finishes

Now I have to write it as

```
 update tableA a
 set columnA = sum(column_that_I_need_to_count) 
 from tableB b where st_contains(a.geom, b.geom)
```

Problem is that it says it doesn't allow count on an update

Create table statements are:

```
create tableA (
id integer,
name text,
geom geometry(polygon, 27700) 
)

create tableB(
fid bigint,
column_that_I_need_to_count integer,
name text,
geom geometry(point, 27700)
)
```

Is there a reason why different PostgreSQL have different subquery rules for updating?

Also how to do the actual update?

Comment: sidenote: you realize `sum` and `count` are different things, with same results only if the value of the `column_that_you_need_to_count` is a constant `1`?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify what database you were using the previous two years, and which version of PostgreSQL you're using now. Note that PostGIS *isn't* a database, just a spatial extension to one, and this is more of a topic for [dba.se].

Comment: You are missing a close bracket at the end of your first query.

Comment: and the geometries need to be switched in the second update query

Comment: @ThingumaBob yea I wrote that in a hurry, fixed It now

Comment: @vince I'm not entirely sure but I believe the previous version (I can't check now) was 9 and now I've asked for the latest one which is 10

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification. Slapdashing a collection of syntax errors is not the way to write a Question.

Comment: your first query is fine under Postgres10. You may have to check your geometries / indexes.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502032/sql-update-to-the-sum-of-its-joined-values

Comment: @JGH the reason why I was led to believe that it didn't work was because there's another query that just never finishes the update, creating the table with 5m rows takes about 8 minutes but updating it with the column of another with a matching column on both tables is taking me over 2 hours 